# Dynamically insert column names into function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I try to insert column names into my query to obtain the max-length of the underlying data-input, like:

```
DECLARE @cols AS varchar(MAX)
,@query  AS nvarchar(MAX)
SELECT @cols = (
            select STRING_AGG(COLUMN_NAME, ',')
            from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            where TABLE_NAME='mytbl'
            and TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
            and DATA_TYPE = 'varchar'
)

set @query = 'select top(1) max(datalength(' + @cols + ')) FROM dbo.mytbl'

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

.. which prompts the following error:

```
The datalength function requires 1 argument(s).
```

I don´t know how to cast the string so that the @cols are recognized by the encasing max(datalength()) function(s).
Any ideas how to circumvent this error? I am out of ideas.

UPDATE:
The intended output should look something like that:

```
select max(datalength(col1))
    ,max(datalength(col2))
    ,max(datalength(col3))
    ,max(datalength(col4))
...
    from dbo.mytable
```

which works and gives me the max-char of any input per column, like:

[image]

Comment: have you checked your select if it returns anything?

Comment: This won't work for many reasons. First of all, MAX is an aggregate that you apply to ROWS, not columns. Using both TOP 1 and MAX seem to duplicative as well. So it's time to start over and restate your goal. Your table has some number of varchar columns. What is your goal for this? Do you want to find the column that has the maximum defined length for the datatype? Do you want to search through rows and find the maximum length value in each column? Something else? A short example would likely help you and everyone else.

Comment: @nbk yes it works as intended and returns data if max(datalengh()) is deleted.

Comment: @SMor I just updated my q with my intended goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to apply the `MAX()` and `DATALENGTH()` on the column before concatenation

Change the `@cols` to

```
SELECT @cols = (
            select STRING_AGG('MAX(DATALENGTH(' + COLUMN_NAME + '))', ',')
            from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            where TABLE_NAME='mytbl'
            and TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
            and DATA_TYPE = 'varchar'
)
```

and the final `@query` is just a simple `select`

```
set @query = 'select ' + @cols + ' FROM dbo.mytbl'
```

You should `print` out the query for inspection, before execute it

```
print @query
```

Comment: `QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)`